# Creating a grouped text log of changed model attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've recently started looking into Ruby on Rails, and I've set up a basic system to scan an parse and XML datasource, storing the elements in a MySQL database.

I'm intending to run the script as a rake task at set intervals, so want to track additions and updates, outputting the new, or changed, values to a text file.

I initially looked at using the `before_save` in order to write `self.changes` to a file, however the complexity arises as I'm retrieving data from two different pages and want to group the log output, e.g note each pricing row is a different record in the same table, ignore the variable names these are examples.

```
Item GUID
- Price US: #{old price} to #{new price}
- Price UK: #{old price} to #{new price}
```

The solution I'm currently looking to implement is appending a `logged` column to the table, if the data changes I can set this to `changed`, or `new` if the record has been added, and use this in a query to find records in which logged is not NULL, and group them by `GUID`. However as this will execute after the object has been saved I lose knowledge of the past values.

Is there a different approach I could take to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a better way to do this. Take a look at these options you've got:

- `audited` gem: https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited
- `paper_trail` gem: https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail
- `espinita` gem: https://github.com/continuum/espinita